# Counting values in arrays, and adding partial counts as well as value substraction in arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this multidimensional array which holds these inner array values:

```
Array_X (
[0] => Array ( [0] => A [1] => D [2] => C [3] =>B ) 
[1] => Array ( [0] => A [1] => D [2] => E )                 
[2] => Array ( [0] => A [1] => E [2] => D )             
[3] => Array ( [0] => D [1] => A [2] => B )     
[4] => Array ( [0] => D [1] => A [2] => C )     
[5] => Array ( [0] => D [1] => E )  
[6] => Array ( [0] => D [1] => E [2] => E [3] =>A ) 
)
```

In this first array, I perform a count of "A" and "D" in position [0] in these arrays. 
"A" appears 3 times and "D" appears 4 times and store this in another 1 dimensional array as:

```
Array_count_1 ( [A] => 3 [D] => 4 )
```

I then eliminate "A" from all these inner arrays (via "unset"), and end up with:

```
Array_Y (
[0] => Array ( [0] => **D** [1] => C [2] => B [3] => ) 
[1] => Array ( [0] => **D** [1] => E [2] =>  )              
[2] => Array ( [0] => **E** [1] => D [2] =>  )          
[3] => Array ( [0] => D [1] => B [2] =>  )  
[4] => Array ( [0] => D [1] => C [2] =>  )      
[5] => Array ( [0] => D [1] => E )  
[6] => Array ( [0] => D [1] => E [2] => E [3] =>A )
)
```

With this second new array I will then need to perform a count on all values which appear in the first element [0]. In this new array (Array_Y) "D" is counted 6 times, and "E" 1 time in position [0].

```
Array_count_2 ( [D] => 6 [E] => 1 )
```

**PROBLEM:**

BUT in array Array_count_2, instead of awarding a full point to each instance of D, E, etc. which gets me:

```
Array_count_2 ( [D] => 6 [E] => 1 )
```

I would like to award a partial point (ie. say, 0.25 instead of the default 1 when a count is done) for each instance a value got to position [0] (after value "A" was eliminated).

As seen, in 'Array_X' when "A" is eliminated, value "D" is to be shifted to [0] in 2 arrays (or 2 times), and value "E" gets to be shifted to position [0] in 1 array (or 1 time)). Their new positions is seen in 'Array_Y'.

Instead of:

```
Array_count_2 ( [D] => 6 [E] => 1 )
```

I would like the array to be:

```
Array_count_2 ( [D] => 4.50 [E] => 0.25 )
```

D: 4 points from position [0] in array 'Array_X', and 2 points multiplied by 0.25 (the partial points awarded) for being shifted to position [0] as seen in array 'Array_Y') for a total of **0.50**

E: 1 point multiplied by 0.25 points for being shifted to position [0] as seen in array 'Array_Y' for a total of **0.25**

I think the key here is in doing the counts to get:

```
Array_count_1 ( [A] => 3 [D] => 4 )
```

and

```
Array_count_2 ( [D] => 6 [E] => 1 )
```

then:

```
Array_count_2 - Array_count_1
```

so I end up with

```
Array_count_3 ( [D] => 2 [E] => 1 )
```

**How would I perform this substraction to get an array like 'Array_count_3'?**

I would then need to take 'Array_count_3' and multiply each value with (**0.25**) to get:

```
Array_count_4 ( [D] => 0.50 [E] => 0.25 )
```

Then add 'Array_count_4' +  'Array_count_1'

```
Array_count_1 ( [A] => 3 [D] => 4 )
Array_count_4 ( [D] => 0.50 [E] => 0.25 )
```

to get the FINAL array:

```
Array_count_2 ( [D] => 4.50 [E] => 0.25 )
```

without the existence of "A" in it (since it was eliminated)?

Thanks for taking the time, and having the patience to go through this! Appreciate it!

Comment: Actually, `unset` will not shift anything. `array_splice` will. If you unset first element of enumerated array via unser, you get something like this: `(1=>value, 2=>value...`

Comment: Easier than using array_splice is probably array_shift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
foreach ($Array_count_2 as $k => $v) {
    $Array_count_3[$k] = $Array_count_2[$k] - $Array_count_1[$k];
    $Array_count_4[$k] = ($Array_count_2[$k] - $Array_count_1[$k])/0.25;
    $Array_count_2[$k] = $Array_count_4[$k] + $Array_count_1[$k];
}
```

last line overwrite values on `$Array_count_2`. Use another array name to keep `$Array_count_2` as is.

Comment: Hi miltos - will give this a try and see how it goes. I will get back to yo on this one. Thank you.